# OpenCL reported device version different between clinfo / clGetDeviceInfo

Tags: opencl, amd-app

I'm just trying to dive into OpenCL 2.0. I'm using an AMD R7 260X GPU with AMD APP SDK 3.0 (final) with most current driver (Crimson-something, 2348.4) on Win10-64 with 16GB RAM. Compiler is Visual Studio 2015.

First thing I did was querying some information on my system with clInfo. Output was as expected, especially the device OpenCL C Version:

```
Platform Name:                                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:                               2
Device Type:                                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
Vendor ID:                                     1002h
Board name:                                    AMD Radeon R7 200 Series
Platform ID:                                   00007FFE91EF0188
Name:                                          Bonaire
Vendor:                                        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Device OpenCL C version:                       OpenCL C 2.0
Driver version:                                2348.4
Profile:                                       FULL_PROFILE
Version:                                       OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2348.4)
```

Next thing was playing around with some of the samples from AMD APP SDK. Quickly I noticed, an OpenCL 2.0 didn't execute properly. I stepped through the code and noticed a function, which is gathering device information with clGetDeviceInfo. At this point, the reported device OpenCL C version (see screenshot 1) differs from what I got from clInfo, and therefore, the samples, which requires OpenCL 2.0 don't execute.

What did I do wrong?

[clGetDeviceInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05tji.png)

Comment: What processor do you have?

Comment: Intel i7 3770. Available Intel-Platform is reported through clInfo, Intel OpenCL SDK is not installed.

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with the OpenCL ICD configuration in your system? https://streamhpc.com/blog/2015-03-16/how-to-install-opencl-on-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Switching from target platform Win32 to x64 strangely resolved the problem for me. clGetDeviceInfo reports now OpenCL 2.0 capabilities for my GPU.